# Calling methods inside beforeRouteEnter NProgress

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vue-options-api

I am trying to call an API before navigating to the route. The problem is that if I try to call axios call inside `beforeRouteEnter` it is working fine for example:

```
{
  beforeRouteEnter(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {
    NProgress.start()
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then((res) => {
      next((vm) => {
        vm.data = res.data
      })
      NProgress.done()
    })
  },
}
```

But when I try to call an API from methods it's navigating to the route before resolving an API and also NProgress bar is also completing before resolving a call.

```
{
  beforeRouteEnter(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {
    NProgress.start()
    next((vm) => {
      vm.index()
      NProgress.done()
    })
  },
  methods: {
    index() {
      axios
        .get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error)
        })
    },
  },
}
```

Can anyone guide me what may be wrong?

Comment: I don’t have time to write a full answer. But in your second example you are not waiting for the axios call to finish, but immediately  are calling the `done()`. Try to use async/await. https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: You should always chain promises, unless proven otherwise. Here promise chains are broken

Comment: Hi @Gabe can you explain more how can I implement this ?

Comment: Yes, I will write an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you set the progress bar, then you call the API with Axios and with `.then` you chain a function after the call. This means the function will wait until [the promise is resolved or rejected](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-es6-promises-for-beginners-resolve-reject-and-chaining-explained/), before continuing. Only when the axios call is finished successfully, the next function is executed in which you set the data and stop the progress bar. You also should use `.catch` for if the promises rejects.

Now in your second example, you do not use promises in `beforeRouteEnter`. Which basically means that all lines are executed immediately. So you call `vm.index()` and without waiting for the axios call to finish the next line, `NProgress.done()` will be executed. Although there are several ways to solve this my preference is use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await), which is just a cleaner way to use promisses and chaining.

In your case I think this would work:

```
beforeRouteEnter(routeTo, routeFrom, next) {
  NProgress.start();
  
    await vm.index();
    NProgress.done();
    next();
  });
}
```

And the method:

```
methods: {
  async index () {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Since this is only a part of your component I cannot test it, but I think you get the idea.

Comment: Hi @Gabe Thanks for the detailed answer , I got your perspective and implemented that logic but route is navigating before finishing the API call maybe its calling an API inside next callback ?

Comment: I think that is because you call the api within the next function. I changed my answer, putting `next()` as the final call.

Comment: I got it but now vm is not available so that I can access the methods

Comment: O I see. But why are you using a method in a component? You could just put it in the router file, couldn't you?

Comment: beforeRouteEnter and the method index both are inside component .

Comment: Yes I can put beforeRouteEnter in a router file but the problem is that let say I have a button it will call a method and refetch the data again I will make it and then code will be duplicate . I have another option to use Vuex and trigger the method from anywhere whether from router file or component to avoid duplication .

Comment: Yes, I would opt for Vuex or Pinia (as that is the standard now). I was not aware of the limitations of not having `this` available in the `beforeRouteEnter`. Probably because I (almost) always use a store and do al my REST calls from the store.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , yes I will refactor my code and will opt Vuex or Pinia to solve this .